# Sort recursive array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this class:

```
Node {
    sortOrder: number;
    children: Node[];
}
```

And I want to sort them recursive with `sortOrder`.
I've tried my method but it didn't worked.

Is there an alternative for that?

Code:

```
nodes.sort(this.compareSortOrder);

private compareSortOrder(a, b) {
    if (a.children.length > 1) {
        a.children.sort(this.compareSortOrder);
    }
    if (a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `it didn't worked` can you elaborate on this?

Comment: It just didnt changed the `nodes` array at all

Comment: I don't think put side effects to a comparaison function is a good idea. Just create a function sort that call sort from array  And foreach children call the same function.

Comment: What did you try to debug? Did you `console.log()` at different points? Could you build a snippet to show this code in action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing sorting on `b.Children`. And you can compare `a` and `b` by using `a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder`

This is comparator function:

```
const comparator = (a: node, b: node) => {
    if (a.Children && a.Children.length > 1) {
        a.Children.sort(comparator)
    }
    if (b.Children && b.Children.length > 1) {
        b.Children.sort(comparator)
    }
    return a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder;
}
```

And make sorting `nodes` by:

```
nodes.sort(comparator)
```

You can see my full example [here](https://gist.github.com/huynhsamha/0272e37439bfed78ada40a7151ecfb16)

Answer (score 0):

As it is already mentioned it is a bad idea to have side effects in a comparator function,
Try this code instead:

```
function compareSortOrder(a, b) {
    if (a.sortOrder < b.sortOrder) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function sort(array, compareSortOrder) {
    if (array && array.length > 1) {
        array.sort(compareSortOrder);
        for (const item of array) {
            sort(item.children, compareSortOrder);
        }
    }
}
sort(nodes, compareSortOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try this, instead of mutating in the comparator

```js
const nodes = [{
    sortOrder: 2,
    children: [{
      sortOrder: 2,
      children: []
    }, {
      sortOrder: 1,
      children: []
    }]
  },
  {
    sortOrder: 1,
    children: []
  }
]

function compareSortOrder(a, b) {
  return a.sortOrder - b.sortOrder;
}

function sort(nodes){
  for(const node of nodes){
    if(node.children.length){
      sort(node.children);
    }
  }
  nodes.sort(compareSortOrder);
}

sort(nodes);

console.log(nodes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debugged your function, you would have seen an error

> Error: Cannot read property 'compareSortOrder' of undefined

So, passing the function reference 'this.compareSortOrder' to the sort function results in an instance reference loss within your `compareSortOrder` function.

You can use the [`bind()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for this:

```js
nodes.sort(this.compareSortOrder.bind(this));

private compareSortOrder(a, b) {
  if(a.children && a.children.length) {
    a.children.sort(this.compareSortOrder.bind(this));
  }

  if(b.children && b.children.length) {
      b.children.sort(this.compareSortOrder.bind(this));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Or provide an anonymous function to the sort function in order to preserve the `this` reference.

```
nodes.sort((n1, n2) => this.compareSortOrder(n1, n2));

private compareSortOrder(a, b) {
    if(a.children && a.children.length) {
        a.children.sort((n1, n2) => this.compareSortOrder(n1, n2));
    }

    if(b.children && b.children.length) {
        b.children.sort((n1, n2) => this.compareSortOrder(n1, n2));
    }
    // ...
}
```

One more thing, you should also consider the case where the `sortOrder` might be equal. Further, if you want to have a consistent sorting, you'ld have to use an additional sorting attribute e.g. `id` or similar

```
if (a.sortOrder === b.sortOrder) {
 return 0;
 // or 
 // return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1; 
} else {
 return a.sortOrder > b.sortOrder ? 1 : -1;
}
```